# How to listen an event on a listener defined after the event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Using Javascript...

Do you have any idea on how to listen an event on a listener defined after the event is triggered?

Some workaround?, I'm looking for an elegant solution.

> triggers, promises, callbacks, ..., etc

The scenario would be something similar to the following code:

```
/* begin of included file: 1 */
$(function(){
    $(".text").on("done", function(event, obj){
        console.log(obj);
        var $header = $('<span class="index">'+obj.index+'</span>');
        $(this).prepend($header);
    });
});
/* end of included file: 1 */

/* begin of included file: 2 */
var index = 0;
$(function(){
    $(".text").each(function(){
        var $label = $('<span class="label">'+$(this).attr("label")+'</span>');
        var $elem = $('<input type="text" name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'" />');
        $(this).append($label).append($elem);
        $(this).removeAttr("label").removeAttr("name");
        $(this).trigger("done", { index: (++index) });
    });
});
/* end of included file: 2 */
```

If you change the order to `file 2` then `file 1`, then the result is different.

The point here is that there are two included files but the order of inclusion of the files could vary.

You can check it on the following jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t10ekLq5/

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by *listen for an event on a listener defined after it is triggered* ?

Comment: Where is your code? orm at least, a specific scenario? Code is much better of course..

Comment: Sorry, I added a sample code with a very similar scenario but simpler for you to focus better on the situation. Thanks.